# Single Table Inheritance(STI) Problems

Tags: associations, ruby-on-rails-3.2, polymorphic-associations

I'm new to rails and I'm having some problems specifying a couple of entities and relationships in my database.

Let's assume the following entities.

### Racer Entity

Where the migration file looks like this:

```rb
class CreateRacers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :racers, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB" do |t|
        t.string :email, limit: 60, null: false
        end
        add_index :racers, :email, unique: true
        execute "ALTER TABLE racers MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;"
    end

    def self.down
        drop_table :racers
    end
end
```

The model file looks like this:

```rb
class Racer < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email
    validates_uniqueness_of :email

    before_save { |racer| racer.email = email.downcase }

    # Email validation
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /([\w+.]+)@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 60}, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

    has_many :tracks, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

### Track Entity

The migration file looks like this:

```rb
class CreateTracks < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :tracks, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB" do |t|
            t.column :user_id, 'integer unsigned', null: false
            t.string :description, limit: 250, null: false
            t.string :image, null: true
        end
        execute "ALTER TABLE tracks MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;"
        add_foreign_key :tracks, :racers
    end

    def self.down
        remove_foreign_key :tracks, :racers
        drop_table :tracks
    end
end
```

And the model file looks like this:

```rb
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :description, :image

    validates :description, presence: true, length: {maximum: 250}

    belongs_to :racer
    validates_presence_of :racer_id
    has_many :stops, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

### Stop Entity

The migration file looks like this:

```rb
class CreateStops < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :stops, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB" do |t|
            t.column :track_id, 'integer unsigned', null: false
            t.column :coordinates, :point, null: false
            t.string :name, limit: 30, null: true
            t.column :sequence_order, 'integer unsigned', null: false
        end
        execute "ALTER TABLE stops MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;"
        add_foreign_key :stops, :tracks
    end

    def self.down
        remove_foreign_key :stops, :tracks
        drop_table :stops
    end
end
```

And the model file looks like this:

```rb
class Stop < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :coordinates, :name, :sequence_order

    validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 30}
    validates :coordinates, presence: true
    validates :spot_sequence_order, presence: true

    belongs_to :track
    validates_presence_of :track_id
    has_one :challenge, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

### Challenge, Puzzle, Quiz, QuizOption entities (where the problem is)

Has seen above the *Stop* entity **has_one** challenge and I want that *Challenge* to be, among other things, a *Quiz* or a *Puzzle*. The *Challenge* **belongs_to** a *Stop*. So far I have the following migrations:

```rb
class CreatePuzzles < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :puzzles, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB" do |t|
            t.string :image_path, null: false
            t.int :ver_split, null: false, default: 4
            t.int :hor_split, null: false, default: 4
        end
        execute "ALTER TABLE puzzlies MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;"
    end

    def self.down
        drop_table :quizzes
    end
end
```

```rb
class CreateQuizzes < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :quizzes, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB" do |t|
            t.string :question, null: false
        end
        execute "ALTER TABLE quizzes MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;"
    end

    def self.down
        drop_table :quizzes
    end
end
```

And the following models

```rb
class Puzzle < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :image_path, :ver_split, hor_split

    validates :image_path, presence: true, allow_blank: false
    validates :ver_split, allow_blank: false
    validates :hor_split, allow_blank: false

    belongs_to :stop
end
```

```rb
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :question

    validates :question, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, allow_blank: false

    belongs_to :spot
    has_many :quiz_options
end
```

The *Quiz* has several answers, where one or more are correct.

```rb
class CreateQuizOptions < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :quiz_options do |t|
            t.column :quiz_id, 'integer unsigned', null: false
            t.string :option, null: false
            t.boolean :is_correct, null: false, default: false
        end
        add_foreign_key :quiz_options, :quizzes
        execute "ALTER TABLE quiz_options MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;"
    end

    def self.down
        remove_foreign_key :quiz_options, :quizzes
        drop_table :quiz_options
    end
end
```

```rb
class QuizOption < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :option, :is_correct

    validates :option, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
    validates_inclusion_of :is_correct, in: [true,false]

    belongs_to :quiz
    validates_presence_of :quiz_id
end
```

### The Question

How should I specify my migrations,models and controllers to accomplish this goal?

I have found a couple of examples of STI and Polymorphic-Associations but I don't know which one to apply and how to apply them to this case.

First I have tried to use STI and declare all the necessary fields in the *Challenge* table and then the *Quiz* and *Puzzle* model inherit from *Challenge* model. The problem is that I don't know where to put the **has_many :quiz_options**.

Then I have tried to use Polymorphic-Associations explained [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) and [here](http://terenceponce.github.com/blog/2012/03/02/polymorphic-associations-in-rails-32/) but I honestly can't understand how to adapt it to this specific case.

Thanks in advance.

***Edit***: I forgot to say that I'm using MySQL. I also have some gems to manage Spatial data types(rgeo, activerecord-mysql2spatial-adapter) and foreign_keys(foreigner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I solved my own problem by applying Single Table Inheritance.

The result is not pretty but it works and due to the lack of proper information on other solutions I will stick to it by now.

So let's get back to my example.

The **Racer**, **Track** and **Stop** entity stay as they are, no changes there.

The **Challenge** migration will look like this:

```rb
class CreateChallenges < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :challenges, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB" do |t|
            t.column :stop_id, 'integer unsigned', null: false
            t.string :type
            # Common attributes to all challenges
            t.string :description, null: false
            # Puzzle attributes
            t.string :image_path
            t.int :vert_split
            t.int :hor_split
            # Quiz attributes
            t.string :question
        end
        add_foreign_key :challenges, :stops
        execute "ALTER TABLE quizzes MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;"
    end

    def self.down
        remove_foreign_key :challenges, :stops
        drop_table :quizzes
    end
end
```

In this table I just added all the necessary fields to specify both **Quizzes** and **Puzzles**.

Now the models will look like this:

```rb
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :spot_id, :description

    attr_accessible :description, :image_path

    # Validate description attribute
    validates :description, length: { maximum: 255 }, allow_blank: false
    # Validates image type
    VALID_IMAGE_TYPE_REGEX = /^[\/]?([\w]+[\/])*([\w]+\.(png|jpg))$/
    validates :image_path, length: { maximum: 255 }, allow_blank: true, format: { with: VALID_IMAGE_TYPE_REGEX }

    # Validates type attribute
    validates_inclusion_of :type, in: %w( Quiz Puzzle )

    # Associations
    belongs_to :stop
    has_many :quiz_options
end
```

```rb
class Puzzle < Challenge
    validates_presence_of :image_path
    attr_accessor :image_path, :ver_split, hor_split

    validates :image_path, allow_blank: false
    validates :ver_split, allow_blank: false
    validates :hor_split, allow_blank: false
end
```

```rb
class Quiz < Challenge
    validates_presence_of :question
    attr_accessor :question

    validates :question, length: { maximum: 255 }, allow_blank: false
end
```

Now to finish everything, the **QuizOption** migration and model will look like this:

```rb
class CreateQuizOptions < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :quiz_options do |t|
            t.column :challenge_id, 'integer unsigned', null: false
            t.string :option, null: false
            t.boolean :is_correct, null: false, default: false
        end
        add_foreign_key :quiz_options, :challenges
        execute "ALTER TABLE quiz_options MODIFY id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;"
    end

    def self.down
        remove_foreign_key :quiz_options, :challenges
        drop_table :quiz_options
    end
end
```

```rb
class QuizOption < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :challenge_id, :option
    attr_accessor :option, :is_correct

    validates :option, length: { maximum: 255 }
    validates_inclusion_of :is_correct, in: [true,false]

    belongs_to :challenge
end
```

This way everything works as I wanted.